# Oracle Forms and Reports 11g R2 installation Error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I am installing Oracle Forms and Reports 11g R2, but facing error while setting installation locations -

1. my System is Windows XP - 32 bit with all pre-requisites
2. I have installed WebLogic Server 12c (12.1.2) and this working fine.

While installing forms, i am not able to process next. 
Error INST-07248 - Weblogic and Middleware home location is not valid.

how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is Forms and Reports use a very specific version of weblogic application server to run locally. If you have sourced your own version of weblogic - I would check its interoperability with Oracle Forms and Reports 11g R2.

> Unless otherwise documented, avoid installing any other Oracle Fusion
>   Middleware products in the **same** Middleware home as Oracle Forms and
>   Reports.

[Middleware Home Interoperability for Oracle Forms and Reports 11g Release 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E38115_01/doc.111210/e37679/fr_interop.htm#CHDEDAHI)

Answer (score 2):

The only versions of Weblogic supported to run Oracle Forms 11g R2 are 
Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.5) or
10.3.6

You can see the full list of versions to download [here](http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/11gshoppinglist/)
and you can see the full install guide with step by step instructions [here](http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/tips-and-tricks-the-dummies-guide-to-installing-oracle-forms-11g-r2-on-64-bit/?relatedposts_exclude=468)